# findElements(By.xpath(".//g") not working inside <svg> tag

Tags: java, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, webdriver

EDIT: a commenter has rightfully noted that, in fact, the HTML code I am working with is all inside an  tag, which appears to impact this particular case decisively.

I am trying to retrieve all the  elements within an element, at any level. Actually, I need to make some additional checks too too, so I need to use By.xpath, not By.tagName. But By.xpath somehow does not work, even without the checks. (Of course it fails with the other checks too - I am just providing the minimal example).

My code:

```
log.info(eventGroup.getAttribute("outerHTML"))
alerts = eventGroup.findElements(By.xpath(".//g"));
log.info(alerts.size());
```

The first line is there for debugging, to make sure I get the right element. Here is its output:

```
 <g class="event-group">
    <line x1="-105" x2="927.4000244140625" y1="0" y2="0" class="events-bar"/>
    <line x1="-105" x2="927.4000244140625" y1="45" y2="45" class="events-bar"/>
    <line id="markLine" x1="0" x2="0" y1="0" y2="0" y1save="22.5" y2save="537"/>
    <text x="-30" y="26.5" text-anchor="end">Alerts</text><g clip-path="url(#event-clip)">
        <g class="one-event">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#9warning" class="event warning" x="240.04638877275397" y="17.5" width="10" height="10" data-id="58fe7efa97d469000d047594_2017-04-24T22:40:37.679Z"/>
            <rect class="event-overlay" x="235.04638877275397" y="12.5" width="20" height="20"/>
        </g><g class="one-event">
            <use xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xlink:href="#9warning" class="event warning" x="-4.624127036138464" y="17.5" width="10" height="10" data-id="58fe238d97d469000d0450b3_2017-04-24T16:10:37.710Z"/>
            <rect class="event-overlay" x="-9.624127036138464" y="12.5" width="20" height="20"/>
        </g>
    </g>
</g>
```

So there's a lot of  elements to find. Yet the resulting size of alerts is 0.

How can I fix my xpath so it finds all g elements under this element at any level? "//g" won't work as it finds all g elements in the entire document (I've been hit by this before).

Of course I can do without xpath, just search by tag name and then loop through the results to filter them. But xpath will probably work quicker than a big loop? (I am not using MSIE for this test case).

Comment: Quick check: what if you change the expression to `.//*[local-name() = 'g']`?

Comment: What is `eventGroup` here in your code? can you provide some more code snippet

Comment: .//*[local-name() = 'g'] has worked, thanks!

Comment: ..but what WAS that? xpath spec seems clear-cut about tag names and yet...

Comment: @alecxe you should post your suggestion as an answer so it can be marked as the solution.

Comment: @alexce seconded, preferably with a brief explanation. I have already amended the question with what I could understand of the cause so far.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason why `.//g` expression does not find the desired `g` elements is because of the [namespaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML_namespace). Your `svg` element has the default namespace defined as:

```
xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
```

Which means that the `g` child elements actually have `svg:g` names.

You can either account for the namespace:

```
.//svg:g
```

Or, *ignore* the namespace with [`local-name()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/local-name):

```
.//*[local-name() = 'g']
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this in following way for what you have mentioned

```
// Locate parent element of <g> tag
WebElement parentElement = driver.findElement(By.xpath(xpath_to_your_parent_element));

// Locate all <g> tag under your required element and store them in list
List<WebElement> allElement = parentElement.findElements(By.xpath(".//g"));

// Iterate all element using for loop
for(WebElement element:allElement)
{
    // perform yor actions for element here
   System.out.println(e.getAttribute("class"))

 }
```

Comment: It seems that OP wants to handle elements inside `<svg>`. For this case common approach is not applicable. @alecxe suggestion seem to be valid

Comment: This is effectively the same as my snippet except with a different logging mechanism (and with the piece that finds the parent element). So it won't work. If I were to loop stuff I could just use By.tagName, but I don't want to loop stuff. @alecxe suggestion was valid.